# Gitlab not returning initial state after revert

Tags: gitlab, revert

I know there might be some questions similar to this, but mine is a bit odd.

I have branch master and A. I want to create branch `B` from `A`, then merge `B` back to both `master` and `A`.

However, I miscreated `B` from `master`, then merge it to `A`. I reverted the merge, but now Gitlab detects A is up-to-date with master, which is not.

Not sure if this is a known issue. Please help, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reverting the merge, try and reset A (`git reset --hard A~`) and, if you can (meaning if no one worked on `A`), to force push it (`git push --force`)

You might have to [unprotect branch `A` in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html) first.